# Eclipse XLRD, XLWT Import Error

Tags: python, eclipse, xlrd, xlwt

I downloaded the latest Enthought EPD python distribution (academic), which comes with python 2.7. 
I am using Eclipse as my IDE.

Eclipse is set up to use this instance of Python. I ran the "images.py" example file under XLWT.

#### "images.py":

```
from xlwt import Workbook
w = Workbook()
ws = w.add_sheet('Image')
ws.insert_bitmap('python.bmp', 0, 0)
w.save('images.xls')
```

and Eclipse returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Username\workspace\XLRDXLWT\src\xlwt\images.py", line 1, in 
<module>
    from xlwt import Workbook
ImportError: cannot import name Workbook
```

Similar problem with any other example I try to run in XLRD, XLUTILS.

Comment: Someone helped me with the answer.                                                              "Most probably: Python is trying to find the xlwt package in
  C:\Documents and Settings\Username\workspace\XLRDXLWT\src\xlwt
  (because that is the script directory, which is given preference to where it was installed (presumably C:\Python27\Lib\site_packages\xlwt)).

Try renaming ...\src\xlwt to e.g. ...\src\xlwt_examples  <----Works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed, "someone" [helped you with the answer](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/python-excel/qjeXy6qHVRk/discussion).

It's nothing to do with `xlrd`, `xlwt`, `xlutils`, or `Eclipse`.

In general, if you put a script that does `import foo` into a directory named `foo`, Python is likely to try to import `foo` from that directory, and fail.

Solution: Don't do that. Rename your script directory to `foo_examples` or `foo_scripts` or suchlike.